# Html filtering for two tables, and letters array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, filter, html-table

I am using the following JavaScript to filter table contents (all columns), but I am facing a few issues:

1- I want to add an array for letters so it shows some words that has same letter, but different shape, like in Arabic `(أ should be the same as آ and ا and إ)` .. etc.

2- I have 2 tables, and js code works for the same only, as they both have the same id.  I know it should be changed, but how to add the new table id (with its different search box, in the same js code)?

**The following is the current working code for table 1:**

```js
const removeAccents = str => str.normalize("NFD").replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, ""); // to remove marks, diacritics
const myFunction = () => {
  const trs = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable tr:not(.header)')
  const filter = document.querySelector('#myInput').value
  const regex = new RegExp(filter, 'i')
  const isFoundInTds = td => regex.test(removeAccents(td.innerText)) // was const isFoundInTds = td => regex.test(td.textContent) // was innerHTML
  const isFound = childrenArr => childrenArr.some(isFoundInTds)
  const setTrStyleDisplay = ({ style, children }) => {
    style.display = isFound(
      [...children].filter((_, i) => i !== 3) // <-- All columns except the 4 (index 2) - // was: ...children // <-- All columns
    ) ? '' : 'none' 
  }
  trs.forEach(setTrStyleDisplay)
}
```

```html
<input 
  type="text" 
  id="myInput" 
  onkeyup="myFunction()" 
  placeholder="search.." 
  title="search">
<br>

<div align="center">
    <table border="1" id="myTable" >
        <tr>
            <td>cédille</td>
            <td><a href="google.com">book</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Le tréma</td>
            <td>أكتب</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>اكتب </td>
            <td>accept</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<br>

<input 
  type="text" 
  id="myInput" 
  onkeyup="myFunction()" 
  placeholder="search.." 
  title="search">
<br>


<div align="center">
    <table border="1" id="myTable" >
        <tr>
            <td>text2</td>
            <td><a href="google.com">book</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>different text</td>
            <td>words </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>garçon </td>
            <td>more</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things to do:

- Resolve duplicate `id` attributes. Such duplicates are not valid in HTML. So call the second table `myTable2` or something, and remove the `id` attributes of the `input` elements
- Add a `data` attribute to your `input` elements to denote which table they are going.
- Listen to the `input` event instead of the `keyup` event
- Extend `removeAccents` so that it will also replace characters with their synonym. You can define a dictionary for such mapping.
- Make sure to also call `removeAccents` on the value that the user types.
- Give `myFunction` a more meaningful name like `applyFilter`
- Use `e.target` in that event handler to know which `input` triggered the event, and retrieve the associated table name with the `dataset` property

NB: I am not familiar with the Arabic script, so please review the `equiv` object definition. The principle is that each key in that object should be a character that will be replaced (when found) with the associated value. You only need to define this relation in one direction.

This is the result of applying the above remarks:

```js
const equiv = {
 "أ":
       "إ",
 "آ": 
       "إ",
 "ا":
       "إ"};

const removeAccents = str => 
    str.normalize("NFD")
       .replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, "")
       .replace(/./gu, c => equiv[c] ?? c); // <--
       
// Attach handler. Listen to "input" event.
for (const input of document.querySelectorAll("input[data-table]")) {
    input.addEventListener("input", applyFilter);
}

function applyFilter(e) {
  const table = document.getElementById(e.target.dataset.table); // <--
  const trs = table.querySelectorAll('tr:not(.header)'); // <--
  const filter = removeAccents(e.target.value); // <--
  const regex = new RegExp(filter, 'iu');
  const isFoundInTds = td => regex.test(removeAccents(td.innerText)); 
  const isFound = childrenArr => childrenArr.some(isFoundInTds);
  const setTrStyleDisplay = ({ style, children }) => {
    style.display = isFound(
      [...children].filter((_, i) => i !== 3) // <-- All columns except the 4 (index 2) - // was: ...children // <-- All columns
    ) ? '' : 'none' 
  }
  trs.forEach(setTrStyleDisplay)

}
```

```html
<input 
  type="text" 
  placeholder="search.." 
  title="search"
  data-table="myTable"> <!-- add this reference -->
<br>

<div align="center">
    <table border="1" id="myTable" >
        <tr>
            <td>cédille</td>
            <td><a href="google.com">book</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Le tréma</td>
            <td>أكتب</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>اكتب </td>
            <td>accept</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<br>

<input 
  type="text" 
  placeholder="search.." 
  title="search"
  data-table="myTable2"> <!--- add this reference -->
<br>


<div align="center">
    <table border="1" id="myTable2" >
        <tr>
            <td>text2</td>
            <td><a href="google.com">book</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>different text</td>
            <td>words </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>garçon </td>
            <td>more</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  The issue of different tables fixed, but the one for the letters not..  If treating `أ = ا = إ = آ`, then when searching for `أكتب` it should show the two Arabic words, not only one, same as when writing "اكتب" or "آكتب".

Comment: You want all of those to be the same? Then put first three of them as keys in the `equiv` object and have as value always the last variant. The principle is that you use this dictionary to map multiple characters to one.

Comment: I don't know Arabic script, so I will give the example of when you want "|"  "I" "│" and "!" 
 to all be considered "!". Then do `{ "|" : "!", "I" : "!",  "│": "!" }`.